# Database copies partially when copying into sd card

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating an app which uses a ready-made `SQLiteDatabase`. I am giving a choice to the user to copy the database into either the sd card or phone memory. The following code works perfectly when the database is copied into phone memory. The 26.5 MB database is copied completely into the phone memory. But if the same code is used to copy in sd card, only a part of the database is copied, i.e. only one table named `android_metadata` is copied.

```
private void copyDatabase(String storage) {

    try {
        //DB_NAME  is defined in the class
        //DB_PATH refers to the phone directory path.
        InputStream in = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File sdCardPath = new File(sd, DB_NAME);
        File phonePath = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        OutputStream os = null;
        if (storage.equalsIgnoreCase("sd"))
            os = new FileOutputStream(sdCardPath);
        else if (storage.equalsIgnoreCase("phone"))
            os = new FileOutputStream(phonePath);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);

        }

        os.flush();
        os.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is that though database is created in the sd card memory, complete database is not copied. The database thus created is only 3.4 Mb is size, while the original database is 26.5 Mb is size I have checked this through the File Explorer view in Eclipse.

Any suggestions ?

**Edit:**
As I am copying the database directly from `assets` folder, I can't fetch a `FileInputStream` or `FileChannel` object. I can get only a `InputStream` object from the `assets` resource.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the given function, hope it will help you

```
public void copyDatabse(String databaseName) {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//"+getPackageName()+"//databases//"+databaseName+"";
                String backupDBPath = "backupname.db";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

and call as `copyDatabse("databasename");`

also please visit

[Trying to Copy SQLite DB from data to SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043175/trying-to-copy-sqlite-db-from-data-to-sd-card)

Comment: I had searched google and stumbled upon the link you gave. But the difference in the two questions is that I am copying the database directly from `assets` folder and hence can't get `FileInputStream`. On the other hand, the other question copies data from phone memory.

Comment: oh ok, than i will try to have some answer and will be back

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the job:

```
void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("mydb.sqlite");
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myInput.close();

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();

    }
```

Where outFileName will hold the location to where you want to store on SD Card

Comment: No. This didn't worked, got same result as I got using my code. Besides, I don't know if your code and my code are different. In essence, they are both same.